# How to include multiple expression in a case when statement with databricks pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

The following case when pyspark code works fine when adding a single case when expr

```
%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df = sql("select * from xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx")
transfromWithCol = (df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case when first_name = 'Peter' then 1 else 0 end")))
```

However, I would like to add another case when statement to the same withColumn as follows:

```
%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df = sql("""select * from retailrpt.vw_fund_managers""")
transfromWithCol = (df
                    .withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case when first_name = 'Peter' then 1 else 0 end"), expr("case when last_name = 'Jones' then 5 else 4 end")))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: withColumn() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Is it not possible to add multiple case statements to a withColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To give multiple conditions you can use the the expr in the following way. The following is my dataframe:

```
data = [[1,'Ana','Anathan'],[2,'Topson','Topias'],[3,'Ceb','Seb']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=['id','gname','aname'])
df.show()
```

[image]

- I got the same error when I tried to use similar code on my dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df1 = (df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case  when gname =  'Ana'  then  1  else  0  end"), expr("case  when aname =  'Seb'  then  5  else  4  end")))
df1.show()
```

[image]

- Now, use the following code to get multiple conditions. You will be able to write multiple conditions but not multiple else conditions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df1 = df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case  when gname =  'Ana'  then  1  when aname='Seb'  then  2  else  0  end"))
df1.show()
```

[image]